# I am trying to convert nested CSS to plain CSS for a card component I saw online

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, react-component

I just started my first React project and I'm facing issues with CSS.
I'm trying to make a card with a hover effect on it, ofund a nice one online but it ised nested css, I tried node-sass but didn't really worked.
I converted the CSS code to plain CSS but I can't figure out the hover effects in the card!!

`

```
card:
<section class="page-contain">
        <a href="#" class="data-card">
          <h3>01</h3>
          <h4>Portfolio Site.</h4>
          <p>My personal site using ReactJs.</p>
        </a>
      </section>

Card CSS: I know it's a mess!! sorry...
.page-contain {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #e7f3f1;
  border: 0.75em solid white;
  padding: 2em;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.data-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 20.75em;
  min-height: 20.75em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: white;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 2.75em 2.5em;
  box-shadow: 0 1.5em 2.5em -0.5em rgba(#000000, 0.1);
  transition: transform 0.45s ease, background 0.45s ease;
}
.data-card h3 {
  color: #2e3c40;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin: 0 0 0.142857143em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #753bbd;
  transition: color 0.45s ease, border 0.45s ease;
}
.data-card h4 {
  color: #627084;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  margin: 0 0 1.777777778em;
  transition: color 0.45s ease;
}

.data-card p {
  opacity: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.8;
  margin: 0 0 1.25em;
  transform: translateY(-1em);
  transition: opacity 0.45s ease, transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

.data-card .link-text {
  display: block;
  color: #753bbd;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: auto 0 0;
  transition: color 0.45s ease-in;
}

.data-card:hover {
  background: #753bbd;
  transform: scale(1.02);
}

.data-card h3:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom-color: #a754c4;
}

.data-card h4:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.data-card p:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: none;
}

.data-card .link-text:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

`

I want to apply the hover effects to all tags in the card section (.page-contain) when I hover over it, right now I have to hover on individual elements for them to act in hover state!!

Comment: Can you post the original css url here?

Comment: here's the link : https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-chaum-qyflp5?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selector `.data-card h3:hover` means: if I hover on h3, this and this should happen.
What you want is this `.data-card:hover h3`which means: when I hover on data-card, the h3 should look like this and that.
You should change other selectors similarly.

Comment: No bro, it didn't work!! It behaved weirdly...

Comment: I've pasted the code link above, in the comment.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you want to achieve. This is how it works after the changes.
https://codepen.io/magdasz/pen/qBKGXRM